# Q Learning tutorial confuse

Tags: machine-learning, artificial-intelligence

I am pretty new to any machine learning methods and i thought i will give it a try trying Q-Learning. So i been reading this article:

http://mnemstudio.org/path-finding-q-learning-tutorial.htm

What is confusing me is that this equation:

```
Q(1, 5) = R(1, 5) + 0.8 * Max[Q(5, 1), Q(5, 4), Q(5, 5)] = 100 + 0.8 * 0 = 100
```

this `R(1, 5)` keeps changing in the tutorial from `100` to `0` then back to `100` again, WHAT! R matrix is static.

[image]

Comment: At a quick first glance I'd say this is simply a mistake in the article. While in general the reward may have a random component, the environment here is deterministic.

Comment: I didn't read enough before my first comment. Going deeper into the article I have become pretty confused myself with what's going on. The problem is - where is the mistake because the whole premise seems to switch from determination of ways to move forwards, to what appears to be retrospective evaluation about the move you just made (why are we moving from random state 3 to 1 and then evaluating moves from 1, without evaluating moves from state 3? What is the purpose of state 3 in the first place there?)

Comment: The more I look the more confused I get. I would suggest finding a different guide :) `The result of this computation for Q(1, 5) is 100 because of the instant reward from R(5, 1)` well, no, because R(5,1) is 0? Also, they put the 100 in the wrong place in the Q matrix in the attached image and I suspect there's a copy/paste error between the equations but I can't untangle what the intended procedure should look like.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think one mistake is using `R(1, 5)` in the second equation. If you read the text, you'll find that you're in state `3` currently, and you randomly pick state `1` to go to:

> For the next episode, we start with a randomly chosen initial state.  **This time, we have state 3 as our initial state**.
>
> Look at the fourth row of matrix R; it has 3 possible actions: go to state 1, 2 or 4.  By random selection, **we select to go to state 1 as our action**.

`R(3, 1)` is `0`, and the updated `Q` matrix that follows in the article also has the value filled in for `Q(3, 1)`.

Then, the formula should be:

```
Q(3, 1) = R(3, 1) + 0.8 * Max[Q(1, 3), Q(1, 5)] = 0 + 0.8 * 100 = 80
```

`(1, 2)` is `-1`, so I think using that is a mistake. The text even says:

> Now we imagine that we are in state 1.  Look at the second row of reward matrix R (i.e. state 1).  It has 2 possible actions: **go to state 3 or state 5**

So `R(1, 5)` doesn't change: it's always `100`. It's just confused with `R(3, 1)` sometimes.

**Update**

Here is another part of the tutorial that I think should be changed for clarity and correctness and what I think it should say, in order. I bolded the changes I made.

> The updated entries of matrix Q, Q(5, 1), Q(5, 4), Q(5, 5), are all zero.  The result of this computation for Q(1, 5) is 100 because of the instant reward from R(5, 1).  This result does not change the Q matrix.

Change to:

*The updated entries of matrix Q, Q(5, 1), Q(5, 4), Q(5, 5) (**as in, updated from previous operations**), are all zero.  The result of this computation for Q(1, 5) is 100 because of the instant reward from **R(1, 5)**.  This result does not change the Q matrix.*

Comment: This makes some sense, but the errors in the account seem pretty pervasive. `The updated entries of matrix Q, Q(5, 1), Q(5, 4), Q(5, 5), are all zero.  The result of this computation for Q(1, 5) is 100 because of the instant reward from R(5, 1).  This result does not change the Q matrix.` 1) Why are we referencing R(5,1) here? Should that too be R(1,5)? 2) If that doesn't lead to an update of the Q matrix, how do we get above 100 in the final form?

Comment: @roganjosh 1) yes, I think that should also be `R(1,5)`, I also added this to my answer. 2) The `Q` update formula is a sum involving `R` and other values of `Q`, so it can easily get over 100 if you let it run long enough. The tutorial only presents one step, with conveniently picked states. Other states will get picked eventually, which will update the `Q` matrix.

Comment: Ok, I can understand that point. But we start by calculating Q(1,5) and arrive at 100. We then calculate a route from 3 to 5 via 1, yet Q(1,5) does not update to reflect this route. I would therefore assume that 2-->3-->1-->5 also does not affect Q(1,5). I'm not seeing the point at which Q(1,5) gets updated or am I viewing this incorrectly?

Comment: Ah ok nm. On the 3-1-5 trip, we only did the 3-1 portion. I understand now sorry. Overall it's got to be one of the worst tutorials I have seen, with the Q matrix listing Q(2,5) as being 100 instead of Q(1,5). Typos everywhere!

Comment: @roganjosh you don't calculate a route from `3` to `5` via `1`. You simply find the `Q` value of going from `3` to `1` (`Q(3, 1)`). `Q(1, 5)` has no business updating at this point; we only care about updating `Q(3, 1)`. We only ever care about updating a single value at a time. To update `Q(1, 5)`, you need to pick it at lines `3.1` and `3.3` of the pseudocode algorithm posted in the tutorial: `Select a random initial state.` and `Select one among all possible actions for the current state.`.

Comment: @roganjosh Yes, exactly. Don't think about it as pathfinding, the author also introduced that misleading bit. Think about it as learning an environment you know nothing about. While possible to use for pathfinding, Q learning is **not** pathfinding. Putting it together with `A*` under such a name is very misleading IMO.

Comment: Thanks lVlad and roganjosh both of your comment has helped me alot